# Where to save JS callback function for retry after authentication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an action that I want to allow only to an authenticated user. If a user who hasn't yet logged in clicks this link, the Webserver will return a not-logged-in response. I then present the login form in a floating "lightbox" div. If the user successfully logs in, I want the browser to retry the action.

I'm having trouble finding a good place to store the function that I want to retry. Currently, I'm attaching it to a global object, which seems very hacky. The jQuery "deferred" pattern seems to fit here, but I would still need to retain a reference to the deferred object somewhere, and I can't see the right place to do it.

Suggestions?

Here's some simplified code (in reality, the Ajax response determines whether we show the login form or a confirmation of the action):

```
$(function() { 
    $('li.secured').find('a').click(function() {
        var link = this;
        var action = function() {               // captures 'link'
            if(RootObj.IsAuthenticated() ) {            // already logged in 
                window.location.assign( link.href );
            } else {
                // pass ourself in as a callback to be repeated after authentication
                // Yes, this seems to work even in the midst of our own definition...
                RootObj.ShowLoginForm( action );  
            }
            return false;           // don't go immediately to the new url
        }
        return action();
    });
});

RootObj.ShowLoginForm = function( callback ) {
    var lb = $('#lightbox');
    if(lb.length == 0) { lb = $('<div id="lightbox" class="lightbox"></div>').appendTo('body'); }
    lb.load('login.html');

    RootObj.callback = callback;    // is there a better place to store this callback function?
}
```

Comment: You could namespace it one level further upon the global object and collect everything about login/auth there. Like RootObj.Auth.callback, RootObj.Auth.ShowLoginForm, etc